# Xcode: I have made a UISwitch and it works fine but then when I switch a view and come back it is playing up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have made a game which has a UISwitch that turns the music off. I have implemented it properly. It works fine until you switch views and come back to it.

Comment: where do you initialize your UISwitch ? how do you determine its value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch is also showing its ON state? There are chances that you may have set the switch's **on** property to **YES** in *viewWillAppear:* method or somewhere where it gets called whenever you switch between views.

Comment: I haven't added anything in the viewWillAppear

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just realised I had it in the viewDidLoad!